# Retrieve and set file details using windows API?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm not able to programmatically get/set file details on Windows.

I managed to get file size, creation time, last access, but those are information I don't actually need.

I'd like to get/set information like "Author" or "Tag" or every other information you can see in the Details tab in the Properties window of a file, even custom ones (which may vary depending of the file itself).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are `properties`. Here is a how-to example:
https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/Win7Samples/winui/shell/appplatform/PropertyEdit

In case the link above will break, here are the core functions to use:

[SHGetPropertyStoreFromParsingName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-shgetpropertystorefromparsingname)

This will return a [IPropertyStore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/propsys/nn-propsys-ipropertystore)

You can enumerate it by using [IPropertyStore::GetCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/propsys/nf-propsys-ipropertystore-getcount) and [IPropertyStore::GetAt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/propsys/nf-propsys-ipropertystore-getat)

Then, for each of the keys, you can [IPropertyStore::GetValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/propsys/nf-propsys-ipropertystore-getvalue) and [IPropertyStore::SetValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/propsys/nf-propsys-ipropertystore-setvalue)

Comment: Link-only answers are generally frowned upon, as links break over time.  Please put the relevant details directly in your answer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau there are 322 lines of code in that complete, ready to use example, hosted by Microsoft on github. I could copy a couple of function calls into my answer, but the DO require a lot of boilerplate code to work. What should I do?

Comment: @VladFeinstein Will this work(for office documents)  if MS office is not installed? It seems its not working at my end if I don't have MS office installed locally.

Answer (score 0):

The properties you are referring to you are not a feature of the file system. Rather they are metadata stored within specific known file formats.

Windows is aware (through file format specific *property handlers*) of specific formats such as Office documents and common media files, and can extract and present that information via the [Windows Property System](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/properties/windows-properties-system).

There a number of examples, including [`propertyedit`](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/Win7Samples/winui/shell/appplatform/PropertyEdit) which is a command line tool that demonstrates how to set, get, enumerate and inspect the schema of any file that has a *property handler* associated with it.

Perhaps of some interest also in the UWP API, that information can be accessed via various classes in the [`Windows.Storage.FileProperties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.fileproperties?view=winrt-20348) namespace.

Comment: The Property System is also accessible to non-UWP apps, via a file's [`IShellItem2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ishellitem2) shell interface. See [`IShellItem2::GetPropertyStore()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishellitem2-getpropertystore) and the various [`IPropertyStore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/propsys/nn-propsys-ipropertystore) methods.

Comment: Will this work even if MS office is not installed? It seems its not working at my end if i don't have MS office installed locally.