# How to read Tags[System.Keywords] from MS office files on remote windows share

Tags: c++, winapi, ms-office

I have created one C++ windows utility to read file tags(System.Keywords) using [SHGetPropertyStoreFromParsingName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-shgetpropertystorefromparsingname) API.
It works properly for office documents on locally (having MS Office installed).

But when I try to read tags from files on remote share then it fails to read tags if MS Office is not installed locally (MS Office is installed on remote machine)
It works if I install MS install locally as well.

Does the WINAPI [SHGetPropertyStoreFromParsingName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-shgetpropertystorefromparsingname) have dependency on any MS Office DLL?

If yes, then is there any other way in C++ to read remote file tags without installing MS Office locally?

Reference: [Retrieve and set file details using windows API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68778728/retrieve-and-set-file-details-using-windows-api)

Comment: SHGetPropertyStoreFromParsingName has no dep on Office, but Office registers some properties at install time. You should be able to read all non-Office properties. What properties are you missing exactly? What type of file are you looking at? Do you get an error? Please provide some details, and preferably some sample code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Neither the OS nor the shell knows anything about Office files out of the box.  A plug-in is required, a "metadata handler extension".  You get one from the Office installer, it must be present locally.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell-exts

Comment: @SimonMourier I am not getting 'Tags'  from office documents(ex. docx). I am not getting any error. SHGetPropertyStoreFromParsingName  is not returning anything if MS office is not installed locally (specific to MS office documents only). I can read Tags from jpg file.

Comment: @HansPassant do you mean, I need to have plug-in(metadata handler extension) on VM from where I am trying to read tags for office documents? I do not find any references for above mentioned plugin.

Comment: Ok, so yes, when Office is installed, it associate a "PropertyHandler" COM object (CLSID {5985FC23-2588-4D9A-B38B-7E7AFFAB3155}, .dll located in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\VFS\ProgramFilesCommonX64\Microsoft Shared\Office16\msoshext.dll on my PC. An handler adds extra properties (including official ones) to a file property store https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/building-property-handlers-property-handlers#before-you-begin In this case, Office handler knows how to crack open openxml (.docx) file and looks into docProps\core.xml file for custom properties.

Comment: You can use Open XML SDK to do the same yourself https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-retrieve-application-property-values-from-a-word-processing-document or you can just unzip the open xml (.zip format) files manually and search resulting xml files like the property handler does.

Comment: @SimonMourier Ok so its not about remote/local file path. Basically "PropertyHandler" needs to be associated on machine to get those those properties in PropertyStore (via SHGetPropertyStoreFromParsingName ). MS office does this association of property handler at the time of installation. Is there any way to do this programmatically in C++ (before calling SHGetPropertyStoreFromParsingName)?

Comment: Is there any way to do what?

Comment: @SimonMourier Thanks for all help. I am looking for a way to programmatically(C++) register PropertyHandler for office documents extension(ex. docx, xlsx, pptx etc.) so that tags on office documents can be read without installing MS Office locally?

Comment: You can't register the Office prop handler by yourself, it's only part of Office (and AFAIK legally cannot be distributed w/o it). The only way is to write your own prop handler, register it when Office is not installed, and implement it using the Open Xml SDK or another way to open Open Xml files.